# RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout. flutter error

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter and am trying to implement custom list view in flutter.
Its giving be RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout error

1. I am not able to get for which widget its throwing error

2  Also please suggest how to debug these layout errors as the error trace doesn't have specific widget info for which error is thrown

please find the below code for the same:

```
      class ChatItemSreen extends StatelessWidget {
      var leftSection;
      var middleSection;
      var rightSection;
      ChatModel _chartObj;

      ChatItemSreen(ChatModel _chartObj) {
        this._chartObj = _chartObj;
        //.........the left section ...........................
        CircleAvatar image = new CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
          backgroundImage: new NetworkImage(this._chartObj.geturl()),
          radius: 24.0,
        );

        leftSection = new Container(child: image);

        //.........the middle section ...........................
        middleSection = new Expanded(
            child: new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
          child: new Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text(this._chartObj.getuserName(),
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                      fontSize: 16.0)),
              new Text(this._chartObj.getmessage(),
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))
            ],
          ),
        ));

        //.........the right section ...........................

        rightSection = new Container(
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text(this._chartObj.gettimeStamp()),
              new CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
                  radius: 12.0,
                  child: new Text(
                    this._chartObj.getunreadMsgNo(),
                    style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12.0),
                  ))
            ],
          ),
        );
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
          body: new Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
              child: new Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[leftSection, middleSection, rightSection],
              )),
        );
      }
    }

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(title: "Shashank List", home: RandomWords());
  }
}

class RowItemState extends State<RandomWords>
{
  final List<ChatModel> items = new List();

  @override
  void initState()
  {
    super.initState();
    setState(()
    {
      items.add(new ChatModel("http://img2.thejournal.ie/inline/2470754/original?width=428&version=2470754", "9:35", "2", "Shashank", "Missed vedio call!!"));
      items.add(new ChatModel("http://img2.thejournal.ie/inline/2470754/original?width=428&version=2470754", "10:35", "3", "Kakroo", "Missed vedio call!!"));
      items.add(new ChatModel("http://img2.thejournal.ie/inline/2470754/original?width=428&version=2470754", "02:45", "4", "Alpha 1", "Missed vedio call!!"));
      items.add(new ChatModel("http://img2.thejournal.ie/inline/2470754/original?width=428&version=2470754", "12:30", "6", "Beta 2", "Missed vedio call!!"));

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,position)
            {
              ChatModel obj = items.elementAt(position);
              return new ChatItemSreen(obj);
            }
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

is giving me below error:

```
XCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (15078): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (15078): RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
I/flutter (15078): This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put
I/flutter (15078): inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
I/flutter (15078): The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is:
I/flutter (15078):   RenderIndexedSemantics#a9825 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (15078):   creator: IndexedSemantics ← NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ←
I/flutter (15078):   AutomaticKeepAlive ← SliverList ← MediaQuery ← SliverPadding ← Viewport ← _ScrollableScope ←
I/flutter (15078):   IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#e8d9b] ← Semantics ← Listener ← ⋯
I/flutter (15078):   parentData: index=0; layoutOffset=0.0 (can use size)
I/flutter (15078):   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
I/flutter (15078):   semantic boundary
I/flutter (15078):   size: MISSING
I/flutter (15078):   index: 0
I/flutter (15078): The constraints that applied to the RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox were:
I/flutter (15078):   BoxConstraints(w=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
I/flutter (15078): The exact size it was given was:
I/flutter (15078):   Size(411.4, Infinity)
I/flutter (15078): See https://flutter.io/layout/ for more information.
```

Comment: i have the exact same issue with the exact same size of `w=411.4`

Answer (score 23):

I had this exact problem while trying to include a pinch-and-zoomable `PhotoView` widget among separate paragraphs of text.

When you compile and run the app, you probably noticed that where your offending widget is supposed to be is an infinitely long black area instead.

The second line of the error reads

> was given an infinite size during layout

which implies that the widget's size needs to be constrained.

My solution was to wrap the `PhotoView` in a `SizedBox` widget.

```dart
...
   Text("Here's some text.\nAnd then there's this image:\n"),
   SizedBox(
      width: 200.0,
      height: 300.0,
      child: PhotoView(
            imageProvider: NetworkImage("http://image/url/here.jpg"),
            heroTag: "Lauren Mayberry",
            ),
   ),
   Text("And now more text"),
...
```

In this example, I used a fixed width and height but you could always dynamically size your widget based on whatever content belongs therein.

As for how to better debug layout errors: my only suggestion is to remove widgets one at a time until the error goes away. It's certainly less than ideal but it works.

Comment: I am using it for google map. Now I am using `SizedBox` inside `SingleChildScrollView`. I have removed `width:` and added `height: 360.0,` in `SizedBox`, so, it takes full width. It works perfectly! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just wrap the widget with SizedBox and give the size of the screen with the help of MediaQuery.

```
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

SizedBox(
  height: size.height,
  width: size.height,
  child: // Your Widget
);
```

Comment: this doesn't always apply, my widget has to be smaller than the screen height.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved a long time ago. But I also want to add something different apart from these solutions.

These days, I was preventing my codes from being spaghetti codes in my project :) For this, I opened and edited additional files. And at that time I encountered this error. My solution was to add expanded. I added expanded to the one I edited in the code in the column on my home page.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).