# How to solve RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout. in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have been working on a project for quite a long time now and this error is stopping me

Comment: Please refer to this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737363/rendercustommultichildlayoutbox-object-was-given-an-infinite-size-during-layout

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping it with the Expanded widget of the RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox widget or giving the height and width value using the SizedBox Widget